# YouTube video keeps player after I go back on the page

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, iframe, youtube-api

I'm building a smartphone app in HTML5 with the help of JQueryMobile. Since I want it to retrieve a list of videos from a user on youtube I used YouTube's API to do that, after I get all that I needed with it, I made a new page exclusively for the player.
When I pick the video, it redirects me to the player I have in my page(an iframe) and plays the video, its plays fine just how I want it but when I press the back button to check my list of videos, if I havent stopped the video before it keeps playing.. Do you have any idea how can I stop that from happening?

Javascript:

```
 function playVideo(id, title, description) {
var output ='<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'+ id +'?wmode=transparent&amp;HD=0&amp;rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;controls=1&amp;autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
output += '<h3>' + title + '</h3>';
output += '<p>' + unescape(description) + '</p>';
$('#myplayer').html(output);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/CnKZh/

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#second', function(){       
    var output ='<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/_js1gWuxB_E" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
    $('#video-container').append(output);
});

$(document).on('pagebeforehide', '#second', function(){       
    $('#video-container').empty();
});
```

Basically when you close page containing that video it must be removed from the DOM. This is the only proper way.

Comment: I got it to stop but now I messed a bit with my player and it's adding an unexistent video below, Ill figure it out! Thanks! -Edit: I got it all to work, thanks for your help man, I really appreciate it! :D